# CIDR added accidently another AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, cidr

I have accidently added a secondary CIDR to a VPC which was already being used by another VPC in another AWS account our company's private network . My question here is if the cidr was already being used ,  how was I allowed to add again to another VPC ? Also doesn't AWS provide a mechanism to check if the cidr range that we are trying to add is available or being used ?

Comment: No, it does not check that.

Comment: So this kind of mechanism does not exist in other cloud providers as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple VPCs with the same CIDR range. This is the benefit of the Cloud! It's great when you want non-production networks to exactly match Production networks. It's a feature, not a failure.

Having multiple VPCs with overlapping ranges will only be an inconvenience if you wish to connect those VPCs together, or you wish to be able to route to both VPCs from the same VPN or Direct Connect connection.